# Как можно привязать кнопку телеграмм бота для перехода в группу в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram

Допустим у меня есть группа в телеграмме и бот. Могу ли я сделать кнопку которая перекидывает в чат группы через id группы? И как это реализовать на питоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать кнопку примерно так с помощью `pyTelegramBotApi`:

```
import telebot
import env
groupID = env.GroupId
bot = telebot.TeleBot(env.TOKEN)
button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("example", url = bot.create_chat_invite_link(groupID))
```